# How to delete multiple test cases in Azure DevOps

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to delete multiple test cases in one go in Azure DevOps. Currently, portal only allows to delete one at a time.

Is there any way to achieve this using PowerShell script or REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Test Cases - Delete` [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/test%20cases/delete):

```
DELETE https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/testcases/{id}?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

So you can loop the test cases id's and delete them.

Example for simple PowerShell script:

```
$url = https://dev.azure.com/testOrg/testProj/_apis/test/testcases/10?api-version=5.0-preview.1
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Delete -ContentType application/json
```

Comment: Thanks! it is helpful. Is there any way i can put it in a loop as i need to delete hundreds of testcases using this script.

Comment: You can create a query with the test cases you want to delete, then get the results with Resu API and then loop the id's.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to create a script to delete testcases.

Comment: A link detailing how to invoke the API using PAT (Personal Access Token)
https://tenbulls.co.uk/2020/03/11/querying-azure-devops-rest-api-with-powershell/